# Angular 4 build error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, build, angular-ui-router, angular-cli

I'm upgrading Angular CLI (v1.0.0), Angular (v4.0.2), and related packages in a previously working ng2 app in order to bring in a newer version of Angular Material. After fighting with several other errors due to breaking changes, I'm left with this on build:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position 15:22 in the original .ts file), 
>   
> resolving symbol ROUTES in /path/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_config_loader.d.ts, 
>   
> resolving symbol makeRootProviders in /path/node_modules/ui-router-ng2/lib/uiRouterNgModule.d.ts, 
> resolving symbol UIRouterModule.forRoot in /path/node_modules/ui-router-ng2/lib/uiRouterNgModule.d.ts, 
> resolving symbol AppModule in /path/src/app/app.module.ts, 
> resolving symbol AppModule in /path/src/app/app.module.ts
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/path/src'
>    @ ./src/main.ts 5:0-74
>    @ multi ./src/main.ts

I believe that the error involves my UIRouter config (in app.module.ts), but I'm really not sure:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({
        states: [
            homeState,
            buttonsState,
            colorState,
            fontsState,
            iconsState,
            logosState,
            messagingState,
            typographyState
        ],
        useHash: false
    })
],
```

I suspect that the second error will go away when the first is resolved. I've attempted to create a function that returns the UIRouterModule config, but that didn't help. Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with an import statement. It looks like your trying to import `ROUTES` into one of your `.ts` files like:

`import { ROUTES } from '@angular/router/src/router_config_loader';`

Any imports should be from `@angular/router` not `'@angular/router/src/router_config_loader'`. What probably happened is your IDE auto imported the constant for you, and it used the wrong path.

I had a similar problem that was solved by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634022/5490505).